# Accessing Files from PIP installed packages

Tags: python, git, pip

I have installed a python package using `pip install`. I have identified the package folders within `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.
What I want to do now is to access the tutorial files and/or examples of that specific package.
I know that based on the github page related to this package that it has examples and I can see the examples folder on the webpage.

I want to ask whether all folders of a github page are cloned in some directory after `pip install` or these two ( git and pip) are two completely different ways of installing. If the last question is true, how do I install and setup a package using the `git` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages include their examples and tests in the install, some do not. The location is also not entirely standardized (they may be inside the package directory or e.g. `/usr/share/...`). So whether and where you can find the examples depends on the package.

If you want to install the git version of a package, you typically clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/someuser/somepackage.git dirname
```

Then use the included `setup.py` to install:

```
python setup.py install
```

(You may need to do that as a superuser. You may also need to uninstall the pip package to use it, if it goes to a different place than pip-installed packages.)

The examples may still not be installed anywhere, but they'll be there for you to see in the git repository – whether or not you install the package.